# How to add an enter press for an input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a "fortune teller" function with one input and one button. The user writes a question and then can click the button for the function to complete. However nothing happens when the user hits enter. I tried a few solutions I found on here, but nothing was working. I do not do a lot of JavaScript. Thank you!

```js
var outcomes = [
  "It is certain",
  "It is decidedly so",
  "Without a doubt",
  "Yes - definitely",
  "You may rely on it",
  "As I see it, yes",
  "Most likely",
  "Outlook good",
  "Ask again later",
  "Better not tell you now",
  "Cannot predict now",
  "Concentrate and ask again",
  "Don’t count on it",
  "No",
  "My reply is no",
  "My sources say yes",
  "Outlook is not so good",
  "Yes",
  "Yes, it would benefit you",
  "Reply hazy, try again",
  "Very doubtful",
  "Signs point to yes",
  "No, it wouldn't benefit you"
];

function ask() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input-box").value;
  var sel = Math.floor(Math.random() * outcomes.length);
  var b8 = outcomes[sel];
  if (x.indexOf('?') + 1) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = b8;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Try with a question mark (?)";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ask">
  <input id="input-box">
  <div class="button" onclick="ask()">
    <img src="img/ask-1.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/ask-2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='img/ask-1.png';">
  </div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to add a keypress or keydown handler for the input field, and then check if the current key was the enter key.

Comment: Or you put the whole thing into an actual form, and use a submit handler to trigger your logic then. Forms can be submitted by pressing enter while focus is in a text field, under certain conditions.

Comment: You literally don't even try anywhere to detect an enter key press in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put it in a form and add `return false` to the `onsubmit` (so the form doesn't redirect). It should work.

Code:

```js
<div class="ask">
  <form onsubmit="ask(); return false;">
    <input id="input-box">
    <div class="button" onclick="ask()">
      <img src="img/ask-1.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/ask-2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='img/ask-1.png';">
    </div>
  </form>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `keyup` event listener to your input. It should look like this :

```html
<!-- rest of your code -->

<input id="input-box" />

<script>
document.getElementById("input-box").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
   // 13 in the code of the enter key
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
      // your function
   }
})
</script>

<!-- rest of your code -->
```